# Optimizing date comparison query in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, optimization, entity-framework-6

I am trying to optimize one of our most important queries and I would like to have some extra insights on how Entity Framework translates certain LINQ expressions.

I am using the repository pattern so my service layer (where I define my queries) is unaware of the actual data layer, which (currently) limits me to using only Where statements. Using joins and other constructs may help but that would require a rewrite of certain parts of the application. I'd like to exhaust all other options first before considering that.

I have come up with 3 variants of my query:

```
// Takes about 1900-2200ms for 120 records 
public Expression<Func<Appointment, bool>> FilterByResources(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, IEnumerable<int> resourceIds)
    {
        // Appointments are filtered on the scheduler's start date, end date and the resources in the current page            
        Expression<Func<Appointment, bool>> filter = (x) => x.Assignments.Any(z => resourceIds.Contains(z.ResourceId))
        &&
        // Appointment starts somewhere between the start and end date
        ((DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.StartDate).Value >= startDate && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.StartDate).Value <= endDate) ||

         // Appointment started earlier than start date but ends earlier than end date
         (DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.EndDate).Value >= startDate && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.EndDate).Value <= endDate) ||

         // Appointment starts and ends outside the boundaries
         (DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.StartDate).Value <= startDate && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.EndDate).Value >= endDate));

        return filter;
}
```

Alternative #2:

```
// Takes about 2100ms for 120 records
public Expression<Func<Appointment, bool>> FilterByResources2(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, IEnumerable<int> resourceIds)
{
        DateTime truncatedStartDate = startDate.Date;
        DateTime truncatedEndDate = endDate.EndOfDay(); // Extension method that formats the time to 23:59:59

        // Appointments are filtered on the scheduler's start date, end date and the resources in the current page            
        Expression<Func<Appointment, bool>> filter = (x) => x.Assignments.Any(z => resourceIds.Contains(z.ResourceId)) && (
         (x.StartDate >= truncatedStartDate && x.StartDate <= truncatedEndDate) || // Appointment starts somewhere between the start and end date             
         (x.EndDate >= truncatedStartDate && x.EndDate <= truncatedEndDate) || // Appointment started earlier than start date but ends earlier than end date             
         (x.StartDate <= truncatedStartDate && x.EndDate >= truncatedEndDate) // Appointment starts and ends outside the boundaries
        );

        return filter;
}
```

Alternative 3:

```
// Takes about 1900ms for 120 records
public Expression<Func<Appointment, bool>> FilterByResources(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, IEnumerable<int> resourceIds)
{
        DateTime truncatedStartDate = startDate.Date;
        DateTime truncatedEndDate = endDate.EndOfDay(); // Extension method that formats the time to 23:59:59

        // Appointments are filtered on the scheduler's start date, end date and the resources in the current page            
        Expression<Func<Appointment, bool>> filter = (x) => x.Assignments.Any(z => resourceIds.Contains(z.ResourceId)) && (
         (x.StartDate.CompareTo(truncatedStartDate) >= 0 && x.StartDate.CompareTo(truncatedEndDate) <= 0) || // Appointment starts somewhere between the start and end date             
         (x.EndDate.CompareTo(truncatedStartDate) >= 0 && x.EndDate.CompareTo(truncatedEndDate) <= 0) || // Appointment started earlier than start date but ends earlier than end date             
         (x.StartDate.CompareTo(truncatedStartDate) <= 0 && x.EndDate.CompareTo(truncatedEndDate) >= 0) // Appointment starts and ends outside the boundaries
        );

        return filter;
}
```

A little explanation about this query: This query retrieves a list of appointments for a number of resources (i.e. people) between two dates. Because of that range, I need to include those records that start earlier, finish later or last longer than the range (hence the 3 expressions).

I tried switching the order of the expressions but the results remain stable. On average it takes between 1800ms and 2200ms for the entire web api call (I use postman for my tests)

So my question is how this query can be optimized? I think the date comparison expressions take the longest time but it may as well be the Any/Contains combination that slows down the query.

Comment: What SQL does EF generate for each of the 3 alternatives?

Comment: Do you have indexes in your database for the `StartDate` and `EndDate` columns?

Comment: @NetMage No I don't. After having added them I don't see any noticable difference. Not surprising though as almost all records have distinct values. Maybe I can index on new Date columns which are basically date-only values from the start and end date columns. That should give better results but I don't know about the overhead of the two extra columns in the table (which already has too many columns imo).

Comment: I doubt if a date only column/index would make a difference. I begin to wonder if the application of the filter is doing something to slow everything down, and not the filter itself. Can you show the calling/using code?

Comment: @NetMage There's nothing fancy going on in the calling code. I've got a web api that takes the three parameters and passes them on to the service layer (which is resolved by the DI container in the api controller). The only thing that happens here is the construction of the filter (see above), invoking the repository and mapping the (projected) entities to DTO objects. Part of the performance hit is because of the complex and deep graph but that's not something I can do anything about for now. The same process is used for all other endpoints and there are no performance problems there.